# iOS 13 - App Crashed with termination reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0xbaadca11

Tags: ios, crash

The app is running fine on most iOS devices, whether they are iOS 13.1 or previous versions. But with one iOS 13.1 device I saw multiple crash logs that contain the following crash reason:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0xbaadca11
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, terminating for unspecified reason
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

And the thread crash report:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad1775f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ad176a60 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ad31e068 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ad319188 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ad3188bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001b7183328 GSEventRunModal + 104
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001b13ad6d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
7   MyApp                           0x00000001023b3ea8 main + 32424 (main.m:14)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001ad1a3460 start + 4
```

So far it looks like it only happened when the application was the background. I haven't found anything online about this termination reason, and I couldn't replicate this scenario in debug. What does "0xbaadca11" mean?

Comment: Has this build been put on the device by xcode/TestFlight/App Store?

Comment: `0xbaadca11` is bad call

Comment: @Scriptable By TestFlight

Comment: @Cy-4AH yeah I figured it meant "bad call", but the thread stack in the crash report doesn't make it seems like the app made a bad call. And the app was terminated by the device, and not crashed, which seems to me 
like weird behaviour for "bad call"

Comment: @user7450772 This happens to me when app is killed. Did you found a solution to this one?